# PhoneGap - setInterval() fails to execute

Tags: javascript, cordova, setinterval

I am trying to build a PhoneGap app that updates the Location every few seconds.  I have tired to impliment the setInterval() function.  But it fails to run!

My code segment looks like this...

```
// Set time interval and keep excuting every 3 secs
var i = 0;
setInterval(GetCurrentPosition(), 3000); // this will call GetCurrentPosition() each 3 sec

function GetCurrentPosition() {
    // retrieve your info here
    console.log('i = ' + z i);
    i = i + 1;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}
```

As you can see I added a counter to see if it is firing... it only fires when I call it manually.

Anyone got any suggestions to what I am doing wrong or need to add to correct my error?

Thanks

Comment: If your app goes to the background, your app will be paused and setInterval will not be working, unless you've added in a plugin to keep threads running while the app is in the background.  Note that even then there are hard timeouts on how long it will run, as well as possibly breaking app store policies.

Comment: Is there an alternative that can be used to replicate the functionality of setInterval?

Answer (score 10):

The way you use setInterval is incorrect. You should pass the reference to the function like this:

```
setInterval(GetCurrentPosition, 3000);
```